# Natural way to look at infinite Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

The question may be imprecise; but it comes to mind if we see any book/notes on infinite Galois theory.

> *If $[E:F]$ is infinite Galois extension, why its Galois group is studied from inverse limit of finite Galois group instead of some reverse way?*

I mean; we consider intermediate fields $E_i$ which are finite Galois extensions of $F$ and considering Galois groups of $E_i/F$, the group $Gal(E/F)$ is obtained as inverse limit.

My question is: take all $K_i$ such that $[E:K_i]$ is finite, and take their Galois groups. From them, can't we get the Galois group of $E/F$?

Why the way of inverse limit is natural?

Comment: I am not familiar with what's going on there, but the first reason that occurred to me is about the case where $E$ is an algebraic closure. A theorem of Artin and Schreier states that if $[E:F]$ is finite, then we must be in characteristic zero and $E=F(\sqrt{-1})$. Not much to play with there.

Comment: In other words, if $E/F$ is infinite Galois, then $E$ is necessarily the union of subfields $E_i$ such that $E_i/F$ is finite Galois. Whereas it is possible that there are no subfields $K_i$ such that $E/K_i$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

One nice interpretation is if you look at the prime ideals of the number ring, the Galois group corresponds to permutations of these ideals. Considering the ideals as points (scheme-ily), the Galois group acts like deck transformations. The absolute Galois group (or an infinite Galois group) is then analogous to the deck transformations of the universal cover (or infinite fiber cover) i.e. fundamental group (infinite subgroups of) - but algebraically, we only have access to finite covers, not infinite ones, so the substitute for the automorphism of a universal cover is the inverse limit of finite extensions. This is reasonable as the universal cover is topologically the inverse limit of the covering spaces.

Also, to recover the Galois group from those $K$ such that $E/K$ is finite, we need to somehow recover $F$ from these $K$s, but note they must all be infinite extensions of $F$ and their intersection (which is the smallest thing you can get) may not even be a finite extension of $F$ (although I do not know of an explicit counterexample).